# Importing CSV file with NULL values to Django Models

Tags: python, django

I'm importing csv files into Django models using a `BaseCommand` as such:
**load_data.py**

```py
import csv
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from api.models import Location, LocationData

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Load data from csv file into database"

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--path', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        path = kwargs['path']
        with open(path, 'rt') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, dialect="excel")
            next(reader, None)
            for row in reader:
                LocationData.objects.create(
                    location = Location.objects.get(name=row[1]),
                    date = row[2],
                    hour = row[3],
                    measurement = row[4] if row[4] else None
                )
```

The `measurement` column has empty/NULL values so I set up the models.py as such:

```py
class LocationData(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    hour = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(0),
            MaxValueValidator(24)
        ],
    )
    measurement = models.FloatField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

However, when I try to use the `load_data.py` which I have created, it resulted in an error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: api_locationdata.measurement
```

What I have tried:
Deleting my migrations files and remigrating using `python manage.py makemigrations` but the error still occurs. What am I missing here?

## Solution

I deleted the db and created a new one since my database is still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you did the migrate after the makemigrations ?
Youre db is out of sync, probably after deleting the migration files.
If you have no data, create the db again and to the migrations stuff. Otherwise you have to do i manually